# Vba find "-" by using seach function and extract only numbers fix errors

Tags: vba, vba7

Could you please help me on below error in vba. Formula works but there are error. My scenario is need to extract in between number (between two "-")

```
Ite1-223466678-ghtrdhjuyr321
Ite-654354477-hjuyt-
Dftehh-767678765-4yutiuy
```

Extract only this 9 digit in between "-" and need to apply till last row of my excel through VBA

Formula:

```
= Value(mid(A1,search("-",A1)+1, search ("-",A1, search ("-", A1)+1-search("-", A1)-1))
```

VBA:

```
Sub Data2

Dim lastrow as long 

Lastrow=Range("A"&rows.count).end(xlup).row
Range("F2:F" & lastrow).formula = " = 
Value(mid(A1,search("-",A1)+1, search 
("-",A1, search ("-", A1)+1- 
 search("-.   ", A1)-1)"

End sub
```

ERROR

- #VALUE ERROR need to fix am not sure how to do if search fails in formula
- RUNTIME ERROR 13 data mismatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub BetweenDashs()
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        arr = Split(Range("A" & i).Value, "-")
        If UBound(arr) > 0 Then
            Range("F" & i).Value = CLng(arr(1))
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

If your data is in column **C** rather than column **A**, then use:

```
Sub BetweenDashs()
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long
    lastrow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        arr = Split(Range("C" & i).Value, "-")
        If UBound(arr) > 0 Then
            Range("F" & i).Value = CLng(arr(1))
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: No luck still same error run time error 13.... Column C I have data .... I will do output in column F

Comment: @Rahul2020  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Yes I tried this one also still same error run time error

Comment: 1)It will run for few lines and  error throughs because of there is only one time "-" ....  In this case can we add some msg to user to check
2) I noticed if there no "-"  in text getting same error ... Run time error

Comment: I believe is there anything missing in condition ....  I really appreciate your time